# Unable to remote-SSH times out in VSCode but am able to SSH while using Ubuntu and PowerShell

Tags: vscode-remote-ssh

I am trying to use VSCode to SSH to a remote host but the connection always times out, I tried using Ubuntu and the connection works just fine, I installed PyCharm and the SSH connection works, tried completely wiping VSCode from my pc and re-installing but still doesn't work. Please help

Here is a output when I try to connect:

```
    [15:53:01.887] Log Level: 2
    [15:53:01.899] SSH Resolver called for "ssh-remote+minion2", attempt 1
    [15:53:01.900] "remote.SSH.useLocalServer": false
    [15:53:01.900] "remote.SSH.showLoginTerminal": false
    [15:53:01.900] "remote.SSH.remotePlatform": {}
    [15:53:01.900] "remote.SSH.path": undefined
    [15:53:01.900] "remote.SSH.configFile": undefined
    [15:53:01.900] "remote.SSH.useFlock": true
    [15:53:01.900] "remote.SSH.lockfilesInTmp": false
    [15:53:01.900] "remote.SSH.localServerDownload": auto
    [15:53:01.901] "remote.SSH.remoteServerListenOnSocket": false
    [15:53:01.901] "remote.SSH.showLoginTerminal": false
    [15:53:01.901] "remote.SSH.defaultExtensions": []
[15:53:01.901] "remote.SSH.loglevel": 2
[15:53:01.901] "remote.SSH.enableDynamicForwarding": false
[15:53:01.901] "remote.SSH.enableRemoteCommand": false
[15:53:01.901] "remote.SSH.serverPickPortsFromRange": {}
[15:53:01.901] "remote.SSH.serverInstallPath": {}
[15:53:01.905] VS Code version: 1.80.2
[15:53:01.905] Remote-SSH version: remote-ssh@0.102.0
[15:53:01.905] win32 x64
[15:53:01.906] SSH Resolver called for host: minion2
[15:53:01.906] Setting up SSH remote "minion2"
[15:53:01.908] Using commit id "2ccd690cbff1569e4a83d7c43d45101f817401dc" and quality "stable" for server
[15:53:01.912] Install and start server if needed
[15:53:17.472] Checking ssh with "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath\ssh.exe -V"
[15:53:17.476] Got error from ssh: spawn C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath\ssh.exe ENOENT
[15:53:17.476] Checking ssh with "C:\Program Files\dotnet\ssh.exe -V"
[15:53:17.477] Got error from ssh: spawn C:\Program Files\dotnet\ssh.exe ENOENT
[15:53:17.477] Checking ssh with "C:\Android\ssh.exe -V"
[15:53:17.479] Got error from ssh: spawn C:\Android\ssh.exe ENOENT
[15:53:17.479] Checking ssh with "C:\Windows\System32\ssh.exe -V"
[15:53:17.480] Got error from ssh: spawn C:\Windows\System32\ssh.exe ENOENT
[15:53:17.480] Checking ssh with "C:\Users\bryan\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\ssh.exe -V"
[15:53:17.482] Got error from ssh: spawn C:\Users\bryan\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\ssh.exe ENOENT
[15:53:17.482] Checking ssh with "C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe\ssh.exe -V"
[15:53:17.483] Got error from ssh: spawn C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe\ssh.exe ENOENT
[15:53:17.483] Checking ssh with "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2023.2\bin\ssh.exe -V"
[15:53:17.484] Got error from ssh: spawn C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2023.2\bin\ssh.exe ENOENT
[15:53:17.484] Checking ssh with "C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe -V"
[15:53:17.554] > OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.6p1, LibreSSL 3.4.3

[15:53:17.559] Running script with connection command: "C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe" -T -o ClearAllForwardings=true minion2 bash
[15:53:17.561] Terminal shell path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe
[15:53:49.572] Resolver error: Error: Connecting with SSH timed out
    at m.Timeout (c:\Users\bryan\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.102.0\out\extension.js:1:584271)
        at Timeout._onTimeout (c:\Users\bryan\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.102.0\out\extension.js:1:680601)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:559:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:502:7)
    [15:53:49.588] ------
```

Restarting PC and re-installing vscode does not work
Also tried using different versions of Remote-SSH and nothing changed